# sql query to insert rows from one record in one table into the same table with slight modifications

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have an sql server table in which i have 30 columns

I need to know if the following can be done or not

I need to write an sql qyery to copy records in the table into the same table with the 28 column's data to be the same and the rest 2 column's data changed.

Can it be written in one sql query?

Insert into table(30 cloumns) select 30 columns from table

The above statement inserts all the 30 column's data as same. But, I need first 2 column's data changed

How do I do it?

Comment: This is easy, but have you actually tried to solve the problem yourself?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Comment: Also, why did you tag Java?

Comment: i am using the normal select query and insert into statement with the 2 column's data changed and the rest remaining the same. but, that seems to be tedious and time taking. please suggest another solution

Comment: coz, i am using java for my application, jdbc

Comment: i shall take up just 5 column for sample purpose.     insert into table(a,b,c,d,e) select a,b,c,d,e from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query table for which you want to copy using the where clause and select all columns and change the columns which you want to change.

Look at the [SEX_NO],[BLOOD_GROUP] column which are having new values.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CONTACTS]
SELECT [CONTACT_ID]
      ,[CONTACT_TYPE_ID]
      ,[FIRST_NAME]
      ,[MIDDLE_NAME]
      ,[LAST_NAME]
      ,[FULL_NAME]
      ,[OTHER_NAME]
      ,'1' [SEX_NO] 
      ,[DOB]
      ,'O+' [BLOOD_GROUP]
      ,[BIRTH_PLACE]
      ,[HOME_ADDRESS1]
      ,[HOME_ADDRESS2]
      ,[HOME_TEL]
      ,[OFFICE_TEL]
      ,[DEGREE_NO]
      ,[EMAIL_ADDR1]
      ,[EMAIL_ADDR2]
      ,[MOBILE_NO1]
      ,[MOBILE_NO2]
      ,[FAX_NO]
      ,[MEMBER_ID]
      ,[IS_FAV]
  FROM    [dbo].[CONTACTS]
  where CONTACT_ID = 1
```

Comment: hey, thanks, working perfectly. I didn't know that it was this simple. saved a lot of time :)